# How can I use style loader without another loader with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am learning webpack but I can't understand why do we need to use style loader always with another loader.

What I have understood is that loaders are node modules with an exported function which receives as parameter the contents of the file being referenced and returns the string transformed so that it can be used with another loader.

This is my **index.js**:

```
import './style.css';
```

And my **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: __dirname,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    // 'raw-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I execute `npx webpack` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./style.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> body {
|     background-color: gray;
| }
 @ ./style.css 2:26-50
 @ ./index.js
```

Why can't the `style-loader` get the contents of the `style.css` without any other loader such as `raw-loader` or `css-loader` ?

This is my **style.css**:

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

I don't need to use the style loader without another loader, is just that I am trying to understand how the `style-loader` actually works.

Comment: the first loader transform the css into a valid js and the other injects it into the DOM.

Comment: BTW, what is the issue of using multiple loaders?

Comment: @lmarqs There is no problem with using multiple loaders. I just wanted to understand how this particular loader actually works by learning how to use it without any other loader.